# How to get data from read replica instead of master db aws?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'm using Laravel php as Application server and aws RDS(MySql) as database.

my database.php configuration is

```
'mysql' => [

          'read'=>['host' => env('READ_DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),],
          'write'=>['host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),],
          'driver' => 'mysql',
          'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
          'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
          'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
          'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
          'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
          'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
          'collation' => 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
          'prefix' => '',
          'strict' => true,
          'engine' => null,
          'options' => [
           \PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true   ]
```

Note : I'm using Stored procedure to query.

There is showing database connection but not showing active session there.

```
$res = DB::select("CALL getuser('" . $user_id . "','" . $status . "')");
```

Comment: There's an example right in the Laravel docs: [Read & Write Connections](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/database#read-and-write-connections)

Comment: Why are you calling a procedure to get a record? Why *aren't* you using placeholder values in it?

Answer (score 0):

If Stored procedure have only Select query then use

```
$res = DB::select("CALL getuser('" . $user_id . "','" . $status . "')");
```

else if stored procedure use any of insert ,update , or delete query

then use

```
$res = DB::selectFromWriteConnection("CALL getuser('" . $user_id . "','" . $status . "')");
```